# Exception when applying changes to EF model via ApplyPropertyChanges in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, edit

I try to save an edited Entity Framework entity ApplyPropertyChanges, and get an exception:

> "The ObjectStateManager does not
>   contain an ObjectStateEntry with a
>   reference to an object of type
>   'MvcApplication1.Models.Product'."}   System.Exception
>   {System.InvalidOperationException}

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Product productToEdit) //all properties of Product are valid
 {
                try
                {
productsDBEntities.ApplyPropertyChanges("ProductSet", productToEdit); //exception here
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
```

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first load `Product` from database if you want to use `ApplyPropertyChanges`:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Product productToEdit) 
{
    try
    {
        entities.Products.Single(p => p.Id == productToEdit.Id);
        entities.ApplyPropertyChanges("ProductSet", productToEdit);
        entities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Or you can use another approach:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Product productToEdit) 
{
    try
    {
        entities.AttachTo("ProductSet", productToEdit);
        entities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(productToEdit).SetModified();
        entities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Btw. are you using .NET 3.5? `ApplyPropertyChanges` is obsolete in .NET 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt solution.

The first solution is working. But the second one indicate that State is a Get accessor only.

Comment: @Pingpong: I modified my answer. Now the second example should work as well.